# Ionic 2: Add new array into array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I would like to add an array into an array object. However, I am only able to add the array into a new object instead of the existing one. Is there any way where I can link the array to the existing object? Its much more easier for me too if I could add in the array based on which  link it is from.

Here is my code:

```
                this.af.database.list(`/users/${userid}/favourites`, {
              query: { orderByChild: 'priority' },
              preserveSnapshot: true
            })
              .subscribe(snapshots => {
                snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
                  this.category.push({
                    name: snapshot.val().name,
                    rss: snapshot.val().regions[0].rss
                  });
                })
                for (let i = 0; i < this.category.length; i++) {
                  this.http.get(this.category[i].rss)
                    .map(res => res.text())
                    .subscribe((data) => {
                      this.parseXML(data)
                        .then((data) => {
                          this.xmlItemsApac = data
                          this.category.push({
                            feeds: data
                          })
                        });
                    });
                }
              });
            console.log(this.category)

          parseXML(data) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
              var k,
                arr = [],
                parser = new xml2js.Parser(
                  {

                    explicitArray: false
                  });

              parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                var obj = result.rss.channel;
                for (k in obj.item) {
                  var item = obj.item[k];
                  arr.push({
                    title: item.title,
                    link: item.link,
                    description: item.description,
                    pubDate: item.pubDate
                  });
                }
                resolve(arr);
              });
            });
          }
```

Comment: which array are you trying to update?

Comment: I would like to add in the parsed xml data (which is an array) into the category array. I tried to push but it will add the data array as a new object instead. I would like add the data inside the exisiting object instead.

Comment: Why don't you push each item to the list reference?

Comment: I could push each item. However, I would like to separate the items based on from which links they are from. Basically, a category has its name, the rss link and the items from the link itself. If I push them, all the items wont be separated.